# Using loops in python to generate variable

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Can I use a loop in Python to generate 10 different variables instead of computing the value of each variable separately? I can imagine doing this in C/C++ wherein I could use an index value to iterate in a loop and generate value.

```
v1=Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result1).netloc.encode('utf-8'))

v2=Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result2).netloc.encode('utf-8'))

v3=Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result3).netloc.encode('utf-8'))

v4=Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result4).netloc.encode('utf-8'))

v5=Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result5).netloc.encode('utf-8'))

v6=Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result6).netloc.encode('utf-8'))

v7=Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result7).netloc.encode('utf-8'))

v8=Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result8).netloc.encode('utf-8'))

v9=Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result9).netloc.encode('utf-8'))

v10=Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result10).netloc.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The more pythonic way to do it would be to either do it as a list:

```
vals = []
for search_result in search_results: 
    vals.append(Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result).netloc.encode('utf-8')))
# Access via vals[0], vals[1], etc.
```

or as a dictionary:

```
vals = {}
for search_result in search_results: 
    vals[search_result] = Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result).netloc.encode('utf-8'))
# Access via vals[search_result1], vals[search_result2], etc.
```

If you HAD to be bad about it, you could do:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    search_result = locals()['search_result' + str(i)]
    locals()['v' + str(i)] = Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result).netloc.encode('utf-8'))
# Accessed via v0, v1, v2, etc.
```

But I would recommend against it because it is non-pythonic and more obtuse than the above solutions.

Comment: Aside from obtuseness, it's not even [guaranteed to work](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals).

Answer (score 1):

This would be easy if you represented your values as collections. Code structure mirrors data structure; when your data is distributed over unrelated variables, your code is too.

```
vs = [Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name, urlparse(search_result).netloc.encode('utf-8'))
      for search_result in search_results]
```

Comment: @user3450198 if you want to get the variables from namespace you could run `search_results = [locals()[key] for key in locals() if key.startswith("search_result") and not key.startswith("search_results")]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list like so:

```
lst = []
for search_result in search_results:
    lst.append(
      Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(
          exhibitor_name,
          urlparse(search_results).netloc.encode('utf-8')))
```

This assumes that you also used a list, `search_results` instead of all of the indivdual `search_resultN` variables.

Comment: How can I use the above code to generate the variables v1,v2,v3...v10 ?

Comment: @user3450198 See Tim Brown's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locals()` to get a `dict` that contains the variable names as keys and their contents as values. In this way, you can access the `search_result*` variables programmatically, instead of typing their names out.

You could then push a new entry into `locals()` for the `v*` variable names, but why pollute the local namespace with them? They are all related to each other, so placing them into a dictionary with keys `v1` through `v10` keeps them together in a useful way.

```
apply_Levenshtein = lambda x: (  
    Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(x).netloc.encode('utf-8'))
) 

variables = {
    "v{}".format(i):apply_Levenshtein(locals()["search_result{}".format(i)]) 
    for i in range(1, 11)
}
```

Now `variables["v1"]` will be

```
Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(exhibitor_name,urlparse(search_result1).netloc.encode('utf-8'))`.
```

Better still would be to ensure that the `search_result*` variables exist in a `dict` or a `list` from the beginning, so that you don't need to use `locals()` at all.

Comment: Note that Python isn't under any obligation to pay attention to what you do to what `locals()` returns, as the docs [warn](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals).  (PS: `vars` is an occasionally handy builtin, and so an unfortunate variable name..)